# Prepocessing data for Keras

Tags: python, pandas, keras, nlp

I'm trying to write a Keras model that will learn to create recipes, but I'm having trouble passing the strings through the model.

My df consists of 3 columns, one of the name, ingredients, and instructions (showing the first 2 lines of the df):

```
title 
0  [Grammie Hamblet's Deviled Crab]   
1    [Infineon Raceway Baked Beans]   

ingredients
0  [['1/2 cup celery, finely chopped', '1 small 
1  [['2 pounds skirt steak, cut into 1/2-inch dic...   

instructions  
0  [Toss ingredients lightly and spoon into a but...  
1  [Watch how to make this recipe., Sprinkle the ...
```

All columns of the df are strings, so not sure what other preprocessing methods I can implement that will allow me to pass it through the model

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to be more specific in your goal and the technical step you need help with. One immediate question is: Whst kind of a model are you trying to implement? And what kind of a trouble are you having passing the strings through the model?

Comment: Noted on the broadness, I think something that will help someone like me in this situation will be a link like the answer provided below. Sometimes a direction is welcome rather than just a reminder of how questions should be asked.

Answer (score -2):

At what stage of the project are you in? Have you written any code yet?

From the question itself, it seems to me like you are just beginning to learn the technologies and the art of NLP. Therefore, my first suggestion would be to head over to the internet and read about the basics of the NLP and text generation.

While I cannot provide you with too many resources, here is what a quick google search yielded to me: https://stackabuse.com/text-generation-with-python-and-tensorflow-keras/

Good luck on your NLP journey and please remember that if you want a specific answer, you also have to clearly define your problem and provide a reproducible code example for the other SO'ers to work on.

Broad questions can only get you broad answers back.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. No answer can be given to such a broad and unclear question.

Comment: Thank you for the page and the details; and noted on the broadness. The main issue is preprocessing strings, I've actually played with pictures and processing those; but with strings in general I guess I need to educate myself a bit more.